# LINQ's deferred execution, but how?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lazy-evaluation

This must be something really simple. But i'm going to ask it anyway, because i think that others will also struggle with it. Why does following simple LINQ query is not executed always with the new variable-value instead of always using the first?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter something:");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();       // for example ABC123
    var digits = input.Where(Char.IsDigit);  // 123
    while (digits.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string which doesn't contain digits");
        input = Console.ReadLine();         // for example ABC
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bye");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In the commented sample it will enter the loop since the input `ABC123` contains digits. But it will never leave it even if you enter something like `ABC` since `digits` still is `123`.

So why does the LINQ query not evaluate the new `input`-value but always the first?

I know i could fix it with this additional line:

```
while (digits.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string which doesn't contain digits");
    input = Console.ReadLine();          
    digits = input.Where(Char.IsDigit);  // now it works as expected
}
```

or - more elegant - by using the query directly in the loop:

```
while (input.Any(Char.IsDigit))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When you pass a variable to a function as a parameter, it is passed by value.

Comment: Such a simple seeming piece of code, with such complex side effects.

Comment: Holy cow, you got an answer from The Actual Raymond Chen™!

Comment: @s.m. A comment from Raymond Chen and an answer from Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The difference is that you're changing the value of the `input` variable, rather than the *contents* of the object that the variable refers to... so `digits` still refers to the original collection.

Compare that with this code:

```
List<char> input = new List<char>(Console.ReadLine());
var digits = input.Where(Char.IsDigit);  // 123
while (digits.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string which doesn't contain digits");
    input.Clear();
    input.AddRange(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This time, we're modifying the *content* of the collection that `input` refers to - and as `digits` is effectively a view over that collection, we get to see the change.

Comment: Am I correct - this has happened in question example because of immutability of strings?

Comment: @fex: The immutability of strings was not the reason for this issue but it was the reason for my confusion. If the string was a collection like `List<string>` i would modify it directly and not assign a new list to the variable.

Comment: @fex: Not directly. If strings were mutable then changing the value of `input` would *still* not affect `digits`... but the content referred to by `input` could have been changed instead.

Answer (score 10):

You're assigning a new value to `input`, but the `digits` sequence is still derived from the initial value of `input`. In other words, when you do `digits = input.Where(Char.IsDigit)`, **it captures the current value** of the `input` variable, not the variable itself. Assigning a new value to `input` has no effect on `digits`.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
input.Where(Char.IsDigit)
```

is equivalent to:

```
Enumerable.Where(input, Char.IsDigit)
```

Thus, the value of `input` is being passed as the source of the `.Where` query, not a *reference* to `input`.

The first fix you proposed works because it uses the freshly-assigned value of `input` on the line prior.

Comment: Yes. One can say that `input` is a ByValue parameter, not a ByRef parameter (it does not say `ref` or `out`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That is actually not true. Strings are reference types (that's why you can have a null string). Which means that the variable `input` actually contains reference to the string. If `string` was mutable, you could pass a string to a function as a normal parameter, and modifying the string inside would cause modification of the original string as well. But since you cannot modify strings, then in some scenarios it has similar effect as passing parameter as ByValue.

Comment: @tomp I know `string` is a reference type. That was not what I was taking about. I was taking about whether the parameter was a ByRef parameter (either `ref string` or `out string`) or not. So we agree. It is unfortunate that the two distinct notions "reference type" (for example `class` (etc.), not `struct`) and "by ref parameter" (either `ref` or `out`) have so similar names. It leads to many misunderstandings. I was actually aware of that and trying to make my wording precise, but still I was misunderstood ...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Oh, you are right of course, I was thinking about it too much.

Answer (score 4):

The digits enumerable refers to a copy of the string that `input` contained when you created the enumerable. It doesn't hold a reference to the `input` variable, and changing the value stored in `input` will not cause materializations of the enumerable to use the new value.

Remember that `Where` is a static extension method, and accepts the object you're invoking it on as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost a comment, but contains structured code, so I submit it as an answer.

The following slight modification of your code will work:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Enter something:");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();       // for example ABC123
  Func<bool> anyDigits = () => input.Any(Char.IsDigit);  // will capture 'input' as a field
  while (anyDigits())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string which doesn't contain digits");
    input = Console.ReadLine();         // for example ABC
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Bye");
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Here `input` is captured (closure) by the delegate of type `Func<bool>`.

Comment: ReSharper whines, "Access to modified closure" for the first use of `input`. Suggest you change to `Func<string,bool>` and call using `while (anyDigits(input))` (which arguably improves readability).

Comment: @onedaywhen Yep! This was not meant to be the best way to write the code. It was just meant to be a "minimal" change of the original code (from the question) that actually worked. I do not encourage or recommend people to code like above. The reason why ReSharper alerts you is that the closure semantics can be confusing to the reader of the code. To get the desired functionality, we do not need access to modified closure (and the asker knows better ways to make things work already in the question).

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering just to add a precision to the other good answers, about the *deferred execution*.

Even if the LINQ query as not yet been evaluated (using `.Any()`), the query internally always refers to the **initial content of the variable**. Even if the LINQ query is evaluated **after** something new has been affected to the variable, the initial content doesn't change and the deferred execution will use the initial content the query has always been referring to:

```
var input = "ABC123";
var digits = input.Where(Char.IsDigit);
input = "NO DIGIT";
var result = digits.ToList();   // 3 items
```

Comment: Just be warned that 'initial content' can point to a mutable structure.  e.g. `input = new List<int>{1}; var even = input.where (x => x%2 ==0); input.Add(2); var result = even.ToList();`

Comment: @NPSF3000: if it would have been a mutable collection i wouldn't have asked this question because of the lack of an issue ;-)